# Keyhole Integration Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

For the following equation 
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^{3}}dx
$$ 
using 
$$
f(z) = \frac{\log(z)}{1+z^{3}}
$$

1. Draw the contour and any poles (Hint: It is a keyhole contour, draw and label it)
2. Prove that the residue is $= \frac{-4\sqrt{3}}{9}*\pi ^{2}i $ (Hint: Calculate the residue $\operatorname{Res}(f(z)$)
3. Show that it is a function of a real space (Principal Value) from $0 > \infty  \oint \frac{1}{1+x^{3}}$   the answer is $= \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9} $ (Hint: Just show that the Principal Value of the orginal function is equal to$ \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9})$

Context: My professor did this in a lecture a while ago and he didn't really take it up. I went to his office hours and he didn't explain it properly. I don't understand how to deal with the $\log(x)/(1 + x^3)$ as usually it isn't that complex. He gave us the answers which I put as the hints. Additionally, this is a keyhole contour problem. He said assume regular bounds as well.

Comment: What is the question?  And $f$ should be $$f(z)=\frac{\log^2(z)}{1+z^3}$$

Comment: Integrate $\displaystyle{\ln^{2}\left(z\right) \over x^{3} - 1}\,\dd z$ with the $\displaystyle\ln$-$\displaystyle\texttt{branch-cut}$ along $\displaystyle\left[-\infty,0\right]$: It's "more symmetrical".

Comment: @felixmarin Hi Felix, my friend.  I'm not sure that your comment is clear.  The keyhole should be along tte positive real axis and coincident with the branch cut.

Comment: @MarkViola The modification I propose makes the calculation a more symmetrical one.

Comment: @FelixMarin  why does it have to be $ ln^2 (z) $ and not just ln(z)?

Comment: okay I decided to graph this and I see the difference in choice of $ ln^2 (z) $ vs ln(z), I want to restrict myself to the positive real axis. Is it still possible to do this question without that restriction in which we will use ln(z) and not $ ln^2 (z) $ ?

Comment: There is a cancellation of the quadratic $\ln^2$ above and below the branch-cut. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets consider $\ds{\int_{\large z\ =\ R\expo{\ic\pars{-\pi + \epsilon,\pi - \epsilon}}}{\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over z^{3} - 1}\,\dd z}$
>   where $\ds{R > 1}$ and $\ds{0 < \epsilon < \pi}$.
>   
> The $\ds{\ln}$-*branch-cut* is defined by
>   $\ds{\ln\pars{z} = \ln\pars{\verts{z}} + \arg\pars{z}\ic\,,\quad
> \arg\pars{z} \in \pars{-\pi,\pi}\,,\quad z \not = 0}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\int_{\large z\ =\ R\expo{\ic\pars{-\pi + \epsilon,\pi - \epsilon}}}{\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over z^{3} - 1}\,\dd z
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
\oint_{\mc{C}}{\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over z^{3} - 1}\,\dd z
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}{\bracks{\ln\pars{-x} + \ic\pi}^{2} \over
x^{3} - 1}\,\dd x
- \int_{-\epsilon}^{-R}{\bracks{\ln\pars{-x} - \ic\pi}^{2} \over
x^{3} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & -
\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}{\bracks{\ln\pars{\epsilon} + \ic\theta}^{2} \over
\epsilon^{3} - 1}\,\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta
\end{align}

---

- The integral in the LHS $\ds{\to 0}$ as $\ds{R \to \infty}$.
- $\mc{C}$ is a *key-hole contour* wich "takes cares" of the above mentioned branch-cut.
- The last integral, in the RHS, $\ds{\to 0}$ as $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$.
- Poles of $\ds{\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over z^{3} - 1}$ belong to
  $\ds{\braces{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3},\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}$.

  ---

  We are left with
  \begin{align}
  0 & = 2\pi\ic\sum\mrm{Res}
  \bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over z^{3} - 1} +
  \int_{0}^{\infty}{\bracks{\ln\pars{x} + \ic\pi}^{\, 2} -
  \bracks{\ln\pars{x} - \ic\pi}^{\, 2} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x
  \\[5mm] & =
  2\pi\ic\sum_{r\ \in\ \braces{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3},\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}
  {1 \over 3}\,r\ln^{2}\pars{r} +
  4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x
  \\[5mm] & =
  2\pi\ic\
  \underbrace{\bracks{{1 \over 3}\, 2\Re\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}
  \pars{2\pi\ic \over 3}^{2}}}_{\ds{4\pi^{2} \over 27}}\  +
  4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x
  \\[8mm] & \implies
  \bbx{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x =
  -\,{2\pi^{2} \over 27}} \approx -0.7311
  \end{align}